# replace First record date with 1900-01-01 Last record = 2999-01-01

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

say I have the following table that is for the same person:

| Id | Start_date | End_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2007-01-01 | 2007-12-31 |
| 1 | 2008-01-01 | 2009-12-31 |
| 1 | 2010-01-01 | 2011-07-31 |

what I want is to have the first date replaced with 1900-01-01 and last date with 2999-01-01

I achieved that with following but wanted to know if there's anything better:

```
CASE WHEN Start_date = MIN(Start_date) OVER (PARTITION BY id) THEN '1900-01-01' END AS newdate
```

Ideas?

Comment: Assuming you also have a case for the MAX, I think that'll work.

Comment: Also it will work as long as you don't have any dates the are the same at the beginning or end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you CASE state was quite close, if you are want to replace the first start and the last end, you just needed to put an ELSE clause in there.

myself I am a fan of the IFF form instead of the CASE form. And I often like to use `ROW_NUMBER = 1` verse `= MAX` But MAX is faster to compute distributed. So if you don't have duplicate values I would stick with that.

so here are some options:

```
with data(Id,Start_date,End_date) as (
    select * from values
    (1, '2007-01-01'::date, '2007-12-31'::date),
    (1, '2008-01-01'::date, '2009-12-31'::date),
    (1, '2010-01-01'::date, '2011-07-31'::date)
)
select 
    id,
    start_date,
    end_date,
    CASE WHEN Start_date = MIN(Start_date) OVER (PARTITION BY id) THEN '1900-01-01' END AS newdate_A,
    IFF(start_date = MIN(Start_date) over (partition by id), '1900-01-01', start_date ) as newdate_b,
    CASE WHEN Start_date = MIN(Start_date) OVER (PARTITION BY id) THEN '1900-01-01' ELSE start_date END AS newdate_c,
    IFF(ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id order by start_date) = 1, '1900-01-01', start_date ) as newdate_d,
    CASE WHEN end_date = MAX(end_date) OVER (PARTITION BY id) THEN '2999-01-01' ELSE end_date END AS new_end_date
from data
order by start_date;
```

| ID | START_DATE | END_DATE | NEWDATE_A | NEWDATE_B | NEWDATE_C | NEWDATE_D | NEW_END_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2007-01-01 | 2007-12-31 | 1900-01-01 | 1900-01-01 | 1900-01-01 | 1900-01-01 | 2007-12-31 |
| 1 | 2008-01-01 | 2009-12-31 | null | 2008-01-01 | 2008-01-01 | 2008-01-01 | 2009-12-31 |
| 1 | 2010-01-01 | 2011-07-31 | null | 2010-01-01 | 2010-01-01 | 2010-01-01 | 2999-01-01 |

The first three columns are just your data, then `newdate_a` is your current code. `newdate_c` and `new_end_date` are how I believe you are want the data to be.

Thus I think you are asking for this:

```
select 
    id,
    CASE WHEN Start_date = MIN(Start_date) OVER (PARTITION BY id) THEN '1900-01-01' ELSE start_date END AS new_start_date,
    CASE WHEN end_date = MAX(end_date) OVER (PARTITION BY id) THEN '2999-01-01' ELSE end_date END AS new_end_date
from data
order by start_date;
```

| ID | NEW_START_DATE | NEW_END_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1900-01-01 | 2007-12-31 |
| 1 | 2008-01-01 | 2009-12-31 |
| 1 | 2010-01-01 | 2999-01-01 |

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to follow up. Indeed I later switched to IFF : IFF(start_dt= MIN(start_dt) OVER (PARTITION BY Idd), '1900-01-01',   start_dt) AS start_dt. I made sure that there wont be dups in dates. so date typically should follow.